# How to get element ID from Iframes in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cross-browser

I have the code below to get an element by ID. How to change this code to work cross-browser? Please help me.

```
var home = window.document.frames["ifrmmain"].document.frames["ifrmchild"].document.getElementById("tdHome");

var homeLink = top.document.frames["ifrmmain"].tdHomeLink;
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `id` attributes on your `iframe` tags, and replace `document` with `contentDocument` when accessing the document of a frame. For example:

```
var home = document.getElementById('ifrmmain').contentDocument.getElementById('ifrmchild').contentDocument.getElementById("tdHome");
```

Answer (score 0):

window.frames[0].document.getElementById('btnSave').click();
  or
 window.frames['iframename'].document.getElementById('btnSave').click();